# UWP - How to Load LocalSettings data Conditional

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, local-storage

I'm working with uwp in the following way: I'm changing the background of  and  from c # code, generating AcrylicBrush and ImageBrush with their respective values, using a Griview and setting the background when an item is selected with Gridview_selectionChanged something like this:

[image: Description]

very well, everything works fine here, but when I save the value of  and  in a LocalSettings Value and try to load it when starting the app, it tells me that it does not support the format or I don't know what more things :(,

The main problem is that I want to establish acrylic backgrounds and backgrounds with image and then when loading the values ​​as I know, if I am loading an Acrylic or ImageBrush because:

- when `page.Background = Localsettings.value ["acrylicBck"] as AcrylicBrush;` it gives me an error
- when `Localsettings.value ["ImageBck"] as ImageBrush;` it gives me an error

And finally, how do I distinguish if the value saved in Localsettings.value is an AcrylicBrush or ImageBrush at the time of loading when starting the app?

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it !!, using variables saving numbers as strings and not complete properties and assigning the respective funds according to the number selected with the items, in the `gridview_selectionChanged`